# Add syslogd as service on Alpine on Docker container

Tags: services, syslog, alpine-linux

I have a program which needs syslog to run to correctly work. I am working in an Alpine container with version 3.16.0. As I'm getting multiple errors from the program (`weewx`), I understood that syslog is not running in the container, so I researched how I should run it, with little success.

After installing `openrc` (`apk add --no-cache openrc`) I tried to add it as a service as it is suggested on the [Alpine wiki](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Syslog), however after running `rc-update add syslogd boot` I got this error:

`` rc-update: service `syslogd' does not exist ``

I don't have a lot of experience with services, so I decided to ask. What should be the right approach to have syslogd run as a daemon when the container is launched? Right now to get it to run I launch it manually, however it would be great to have it run automatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this and am a little disappointed that this has been unanswered for 7 months and isn't already covered by the Alpine wiki.

1. The command is actually `rc-update add syslog boot`, not syslogd
2. If you haven't already, on Alpine < 3.17, you need to add *openrc* and *busybox-initscripts* with `apk add openrc busybox-initscripts`. On Alpine >= 3.17, you can add a single package `apk add busybox-openrc`